# Run multiple SELECT statements from two unrelated tables with different number and type of column in MS Access Database

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, select, multiple-tables

I have a database which has two unrelated tables, each with different column number of columns and column datatype, How do I run multiple select query which fetches me data from both the tables to be compared with the user input.? Any help is much appreciated. I m using a MS-Access Database.

Comment: Use `union all`. Cast all columns to TEXT (using `CStr` function), and make sure that you use placeholders `'' AS dummyColumn` for the table where number of columns is less then the other one

Comment: In case, its one at a time. How do I compare my user input with the data from both tables? I mean how to get this done.